# Cycling through the Zeta Garden: Zeta functions for graphs, cycle index polynomials, and determinants

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, polynomials, sequences-and-series, zeta-functions

Zeta functions abound in mathematics. Audrey Terras describes in [Zeta Functions and Chaos](http://math.ucsd.edu/~aterras/msripaper.pdf) three zeta functions--the [zeta fct. of a projective non-singular algebraic variety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_zeta_function); the [Artin-Mazur zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin-Mazur_zeta_function); and a special [Reulle (aka dynamical systems or Smale) zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruelle_zeta_function), the [Ihara zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ihara_zeta_function) for a graph $G$--all can be expressed in the same basic form:

$$\zeta(u)=\exp\left ( \sum_{m\geq 1} \frac{N_mu^m}{m} \right ).$$

For graph zeta functions $\zeta(u,G_n)$ typically $N_m$ is the number of closed walks of $m$ steps (with some qualifications) on the graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and is related to the trace of the power of an edge adjacency matrix. For a vertex [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) $A_n$,  also $N_m = \operatorname{tr}[A_n^m]$ (e.g., [A054878](https://oeis.org/A054878) and [A092297](https://oeis.org/A092297)). (Edited per draks' comment.)

You can use the general heuristic $O=KPK^{-1}\Leftrightarrow P=K^{-1}OK$ to obtain

$$\operatorname{tr}(A)=\ln[\operatorname{det}[\exp(A)]] \Leftrightarrow \operatorname{det}(A)=\exp[\operatorname{tr}[\ln(A)]]$$

and then

$$\operatorname{det}(I-uA_n)=\exp[\operatorname{tr}[\ln(I-uA_n)]]=\exp\left( -\sum_{m\geq 1} \frac{\operatorname{tr}(A_n^m)u^m}{m} \right)$$
$$=\exp\left (-\sum_{m\geq 1} \frac{N_mu^m}{m} \right ),$$

so

$$\zeta(u;G_n)=\frac{1}{\operatorname{det}(I-uA_n)}=\exp\left(\sum_{m\geq 1} \frac{\operatorname{tr}(A_n^m)u^m}{m} \right)=\exp\left(-:\ln(1-ua): \right).$$ where $a^k=a_k=\operatorname{tr}(A_n^k)$ for $k>0$.

This last expression is the umbral form for the exponential generating function for the [cycle index polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index) ([OEIS-A036039](https://oeis.org/A036039)) for the symmetric group (mod signs).

The Appell sequence in [MO-Q111165](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111165/riemann-zeta-function-at-positive-integers-and-an-appell-sequence-of-polynomials) incorporating the Riemann zeta function reverses the last relation in some sense:

$$\exp\left (-\beta p_{.}(z)\right )=\exp\left [-(z+\gamma)\beta -\sum_{k=2}^{\infty } \frac{\zeta (k)\beta ^k}{k}  \right ]=\exp\left [ :\ln(1-b\beta ) :\right ]$$ where $b^1=b_{1}=(z+\gamma)$ and $b^k=b_k=\zeta(k)$ for $k>1$.

For easy reference:
$$p_{0}(x)=1$$
$$p_{1}(x)=x+\gamma$$
$$p_2(x)=(x+\gamma)^2-\zeta(2)$$
$$p_3(x)=(x+\gamma)^3-3\zeta(2)(x+\gamma)+2\zeta(3)$$
$$p_4(x)=(x+\gamma)^4-6\zeta(2)(x+\gamma)^2+8\zeta(3)(x+\gamma)+3[\zeta^2(2)-2\zeta(4)]$$

**These polynomials are the first few cycle index polynomials for the symmetric group. I'd like to relate each $p_n(x)$ to the characteristic polynomial of a matrix with a null main diagonal.**

For example, for such a 3x3 matrix the char polynomial is

$$ \sigma^3-(a_{12}a_{21}+a_{13}a_{31}+a_{23}a_{32})\sigma+(a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}+a_{13}a_{32}a_{21}).$$

Picture a triangle with the vertices ($v$) labelled 1 to 3. Make an orbit/cycle/closed loop, or path, traversing the triangle from $v_1$ through $v_2$ and $v_3$ and then to $v_1$. Denote this path of three steps and length three by $a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}$ and assign it the "moment/transition amplitude" of $\zeta(3)$. Likewise, assign the amplitude $\zeta(2)$ to paths of two steps and length one $a_{12}a_{21}$, an amplitude of $\sigma=x+\gamma$ to a self- or null-loop, and so on. This generates $p_3(x)$.

Similarly, consider a square with labeled vertices and edges between all pairs of vertices. With cycles/orbits/closed paths of opposing circulation considered distinct cycles, the associated 4x4 determinant generates six paths each with four steps and length four, e.g., $a_{12}a_{24}a_{43}a_{31}$, that can be assigned an amplitude of $\zeta(4)$ each and three sets of two paths of two steps and length one, e.g., $a_{13}a_{31}a_{24}a_{42}$, that can be assigned an amplitude of $\zeta^{2}(2)$. The algorithm can be continued to the other terms to generate $p_4(x)$.

**How to prove that the algorithm will work for all $p_n(x)$, i.e., that each $p_n(x)$ can be generated in the above manner from an $n$ by $n$ "adjacency" matrix?**

[Nov. 15, 2013 update: Replacing $p_1(x)=x+\gamma$ by $x$ and the $\zeta(n)$ by $1$ gives the characteristic polynomials (mod signs) of the adjacency matrix of the complete n-graph (see [A055137](https://oeis.org/A055137)).]

Comment: Aren't your "adjacency" matrices just symmetric matrices? In that case, a polynomial can be generated if and only if its roots are all real.

Comment: By "adjacency" matrix I really mean the matrix of indeterminates $a_{ij}$ with $a_{ii}=0$ on the main diagonal. It can be thought of as an "adjacency" matrix from which the char polynoms, in $\sigma$ and the indeterminates, can be formed, which will not have a $\sigma^{n-1}$ term since the trace is zero (neither do the p_n(x)). The question is really whether I can make the transformation as indicated from these indeterminates in the char polynoms to the appropriate $\zeta(j)$ amplitudes to obtain the $p_n(x)$. That might lead to physical/geometric interpretations of these zeta terms.

Comment: To assign values to the $a_{ij}$ indeterminates before the transformation is made would be like taking the derivative of a function by first assigning a numerical value to the independent variable at some point. The derivative would always return a zero then. However, we are free to fix parameters to determine the function we are interested in, same as making the main diagonal null.

Comment: Call it a pseudo-adjacency matrix since assigning ones to all the off-diagonal elements would give the adjacency matrix for a complete n-graph and a characteristic polynomial with the coefficients http://oeis.org/A055137, which appear in the $p_n(x)$ as noted in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/111165/riemann-zeta-function-at-positive-integers-and-an-appell-sequence-of-polynomials.  

Comment: Actually, better to call it an umbral adjacency matrix to be evaluated over cycles as a determinant for a characteristic polynomial. See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/112062/geometric-physical-probabilistic-interpretations-of-riemann-zetan1

Comment: When I compare your Ihara $\zeta$ function with the one at Wikipedia, I assume that your $A_n$ in fact *is Hashimoto's edge adjacency operator $T$, from $
    \zeta_G(u) = \frac{1}{\det (I-Tu)}~, $.* In addition when you power up to $A_n^m$, the trace would count all returning paths including non-prime ones (with backtracking). I thought it only counts prime walks, see [here (Chap 2.)](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v16i1r84/pdf)...

Comment: @draks Nice reference.  I introduced the graph zeta functions as analogs and as background for my ideas. I didn't really expect an exact match of relations.

Comment: Nonetheless, I think the graph zeta function example is not right, right?

Comment: Maybe you can help answering this question: [How to get from Chebyshev to Ihara?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/583883/19341)

Comment: For the Ihara graph zeta fct., Terras gives a formula involving the edge adjacency matrix, but my OEIS examples are misleading since they are vertex adjacency matrices; nevertheless, they are also related to closed walks on a graph, which is what I wished to emphasize.

Comment: Tom, I'm confused. I thought the $N_m$ are closed loops **without** back tracking. But your formula the calculate it just uses powers of $A_n$ which includes backtracking. I got a nice answer by Chris Godsil, that shows a way to get returning paths without backtracking. It is linked to the question I referenced above...

Comment: Draks, if you read carrefully the example of the 4x4 determinant, you will see backtracking is involved--"two steps and length one."

Comment: Hi again. Why do you say $\operatorname{det}(I-tA_n)$ and not $ \zeta_G(u) = \frac{(1-t^2)^{\chi(G)-1}}{\det(I - At + (k-1)t^2I)} $ like in [Wiki:Ihara $\zeta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ihara_zeta_function)? Forgetting the inverse for the moment...

Comment: Is this why your "Ihara" zeta function deals with backtracking (resp. powers of $A$) and neither [mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583883/how-to-get-from-chebyshev-to-ihara) nor [M. Horton's](http://math.ucsd.edu/~aterras/snowbird.pdf) Definition
(*Def. 2.7.: The closed path counting function $N_m$
is the number of closed paths  $C$
of length $m$ in $G$ **without** backtracking or tails.*) does? I think that it's related to Chebychev polynomials...

Comment: @Draks: I'm no expert on the Ihara zeta function. Just going by equation 8 of Terras' paper and noting the general relation between edge or vertex adjacency matrices, traces, and enumeration of paths. If you find a connection to Chebyshev polynomials, that would be interesting.

Comment: I see. But shouldn't then bettter write $N_m = tr[(W_1)_n^m]$ like in Terras' paper?

Comment: @Draks: I'm denoting the matrices for the OEIS examples, not specifically for the Ihara zeta.

Comment: Sorry for my narrow focus. Maybe the naming of the matrices kinda confused me...

Comment: @Draks, there is a connection between the Chebyshev polynomials and the Faber polynomials (a.k.a. Shur polynomials), which 'invert" the cyclic partition polynomials (a.k.a. the refined partition polynomials of the first kind--signed OEIS A036039) to isolate the indeterminates in their definition.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have something where I can read on this?

Comment: @Draks, see http://oeis.org/A263916 and http://oeis.org/A127672 along with the Damianou and Damianou and Evripidou links.

Comment: With $x=0$, a relation to multiple zeta values is given in "Analytic renormalization of multiple zeta functions. Geometry and combinatorics of the generalized Euler reflection formula for MZV" by Vieru (https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.04703). (He seems not to have acquainted himself with the lit on the topic despite noting relevance to A036039 and then saying, "At the moment <2016-17> we are writing this paper, nothing is said there about the Gamma function and the related series . . . ." This is despite my clear references (2012) to the Riemann zeta function and to this post in the entry.)

Comment: The relation to the Euler gamma function is explicit in the MO-Q "Riemann zeta function at positive integers and an Appell sequence of polynomials related to fractional calculus" (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111165/riemann-zeta-function-at-positive-integers-and-an-appell-sequence-of-polynomials) and refs to relations to MZVs are in the comments there.

Answer (score 2):

I think the validity of the algorithm is corroborated by the relation between the trace and determinant of $m$-dimensional square matrices $A$ inherent in the Cayley-Hamilton theorem applied to the characteristic polynomial of $A$ as explained in Wikipedia.

The relation between the $\det A$ and $(\operatorname{tr} A^k)^j$ for $k,j<m+1$ is precisely that given by the cycle index partition polynomials, and the cycle mapping is clearly shown by Mark Dominus in the link in [OEIS/A036039](https://oeis.org/A036039). Substitute $\zeta(k)^j$ for $(\operatorname{tr}(A^k))^j$ in the Wikipedia entry, just as above, but how to formally prove the relation between the indices mapping above and the cycle mapping still is a mystery to me.

---

Edit Oct. 9, 2020

(The Wikipedia article has changed quite a lot.) I've finally written up a draft compiling some old notes of mine on this and related topics and posted it on my blog as "Appells and Roses: Newton, Leibniz, Euler, Riemann and Symmetric Polynomials." In looking for further reading material, I found Qiaochu Yuan's excellent blog post "GILA VI: The cycle index polynomials of the symmetric groups," which elucidates the combinatorial interpretation of the generating function as enumeration of cycles, an instance of Polya's counting theorem.

Comment: Related: http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.05771

Comment: Related: "Combinatorial aspects of elliptic curves" by Musiker http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.3179

Comment: Article in March comment is "Seiberg Duality, Quiver Gauge Theories, and Ihara Zeta Function" by Da Zhou, Yan Xiao, Yang-Hui He

Comment: See also p. 38 of "Algebraic and geometric methods in enumerative combinatorics" by Ardila (https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.2562).

Comment: Related: pg. 44 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01770  "Notes on the Riemann Hypothesis" by Ricardo Pérez-Marco

Comment: Related: "The Riemann Hypothesis over Finite Fields:
From Weil to the Present Day" by James S. Milne

Comment: See the Hasse-Weil zeta function in https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.10904 "Computational number theory in relation to L-functions" by Henri Cohen

Comment: Related "Random matrix theory and number theory" by Snaith and Keating Eqn. 1.6.1

Comment: See the zeta function for a Caliba-Yau variety on p. 5 of "Modularity of Calabi–Yau varieties: 2011 and beyond" by Noriko Yui

Comment: See the zeta function, Eqn, 2.25, on p. 15 (and 2.30, p. 16) of  ”New Veneziano amplitudes from old Fermat 
 (hyper) surfaces" by  A. L. Kholodenko (https://cds.cern.ch/record/597592/files/0212189.pdf)

Comment: See discussion of the Weil conjecture on p. 4 of "The Rising Sea:
Grothendieck on simplicity and generality I" by McLarty  (http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/Mathbiographies/mclarty1.pdf)

Comment: Related to the plethystic exponential on p. 163 of "The Calabi-Yau Landscape: from Geometry, to Physics, to Machine-Learning" by He (https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.02893). See also p. 145 and "Counting BPS Operators in Gauge Theories: Quivers, Syzygies and Plethystics" by Benvenuti, Feng, Hanany, and He (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0608050)

Comment: See "Répartition asymptotique des valeurs propres
de l'opérateur de Hecke $T_p$" by Serre https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1997-10-01/S0894-0347-97-00220-8/

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70605/from-zeta-functions-to-curves/70606#70606

Comment: Related: "Zeta functions in algebraic geometry" by Mircea Mustata

Comment: "Dynamical zeta functions and the distribution of orbits" by Mark Pollicott      https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/mark_pollicott/p3/zeta-function-survey-final.pdf

Comment: "Bost-Connes systems and F1-structures in Grothendieck rings, spectra, and Nori motives" by Lieber, Manin, Marcolli https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.00020

Comment: "Hyperelliptic curves, L-polynomials, and random matrices" by Kiran S. Kedlaya, Andrew V. Sutherland  https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.4462

Comment: Similar perspective in "A Combinatorial Approach to Matrix Algebra" by Zeilberger.

Comment: More relations to combinatorics in "A Combinatorial Comparison of Elliptic Curves and Critical Groups of Graphs" by Gregg Musiker.

Comment: Form in "Crystalline cohomology, Dieudonne modules and Jacobi sums" by Katz (https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nmk/old/CrCohDModJacSum.pdf), "Navigating the motivic world" by Dugger (https://pages.uoregon.edu/ddugger/wbook.pdf), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures, “The Riemann Hypothesis over Finite Fields From Weil to the Present Day” by Milne https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/pRH.pdf

Comment: See comments to "Feynman’s Fabulous Formula" by Bartlett https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2015/06/feynmans_fabulous_formula.html

Comment: See the pdf "Discrete Geometric Analysis" and the slides “Discrete Geometric Analysis: Graph theory from the view of analysis and geometry” by  Toshikazu Sunada https://t1.daumcdn.net/cfile/blog/135867474EF4EE2F2B?download

Comment: "Nonstandard Mathematics and New Zeta and L-Functions" by B. Clare

Comment: "The anatomy of integers and permutations" by Granville.

Comment: The zeta function in symbolic dynamics: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Symbolic_dynamics

Comment: "Dynamical zeta functions, congruences in Nielsen theory and Reidemeister torsion" by Fel'shtyn and Hill.

Comment: See "Spectral functions in mathematics and physics" by
Klaus Kirsten https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0005133

Comment: "On formal groups and geometric quantization" by Morava https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.06181

Comment: "A homotopical algebra of graphs related to zeta series" (https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3859) and "Symbolic dynamics and the category of graphs" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.1805)  by Bisson and Tsemo.

Comment: The cycle index polynomial generating function occurs repeatedly in "A Combinatorial lemma and its application to probability theory" by Spitzer.

Comment: Note "Combinatorial Proofs of Bass's Evaluation of the Ihara-Selberg Zeta function for a Graph" by Dominique Foata and Doron Zeilberger (https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimhtml/bass.html).

Comment: The symmetric functions also appear in eqns. A.22-25  on pg. 52 of  "Classical A-n-W- geometry" by Gervais and Matsuo  (https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-152/issue-2/Classical-A_n-W-geometry/cmp/1104252412.pdf)

Comment: Related: "Feynman identity for planar graphs" by da Costa https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.09181

Comment: Related: The MO-Q "Motivation for zeta function of an algebraic variety" https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325186/motivation-for-zeta-function-of-an-algebraic-variety

Comment: See "An overview of Deligne's proof of the Riemann hypothesis for varieties over finite fields" by Nicholas Katz https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nmk/old/DeligneRHOverview.pdf